# How to add the different density images under the drawable folder?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I am facing the issue in adding the different density images in drawable folder in android studio.[image]

In the above image i added the images in drawable folder with single density image. I want to add the different density images in a single directory .In below image drawar_shadow.png directory has multiple density images.How can i create the directory like that and add the different density images.I searched in the stack overflow ,i didn't get any idea top solve this.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do this. What you see is a simple visualisation of every existing density variation of the image you added.

Comment: switch to project view

Answer (score 0):

The `drawar_shadow.png` you are mentioning is in different folders on your filesystem in actual. This is `Android Studio`'s way of showing it you. You can just add your images in respective folders and Android Studio will show them like this.

Comment: when i added the image with same file name ,the image is overrided instead of creating new images

Comment: You will have to add image in different drawable directory on your filesystem like `drawable-hdpi` `drawable-xhdpi` and so on. Android Studio will take care of this and show you a single folder for that image.

Comment: In the drawable -xhdpi we can add more than one images in single folder

Comment: so suppose you have an image called abc.png and you have 4 variants of it, like `hdpi`, `xhdpi`, `xxhdpi` and `xxxhdpi`, you should put each variant in respective folders like `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-xhdpi` and so on. Android studio will show you single image with 4 variants like the one you posted `drawe-shadow`

Answer (score 0):

Select Project instead of Android in the top dropdown 
go to res/ and create your folders with different density there.. OR simply you can use mipmap folder for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

All or Correct Change the Project structure instead of Android Structure. Just your view display separate folder

[image]

For Others... add image with different density

*[image: Try this]*

[image]

- button is pressed and select the picture and click ok

if u want change the directory edit button is press.

Comment: Btw, I tried installing this plug in recently (5/17/2018) and it does not work

Comment: Reinstall the plug-in or alternate create the folder and download different size images from nine patch generator.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I have found to have the proper "directory" structure appear under the drawable folder for my icons is this. Follow the steps:

1. Right click "Drawable"
2. Click on "New", then "Image Asset"
3. Change "Asset Type" to "Action Bar and Tab Icons"
4. For "Foreground" choose "ClipArt"
5. For "Clipart" click and "Choose" button and pick any icon
6. For "Resource Name" type in you icon file name

Now the pseudo-directories have been created for you under the "Drawable" folder inside the "res" in the  Android view.

To add new icons just copy and paste them in drawable the popup will appear showing the different options select according to your need and add.