# Custom made drawable with own png file leads to OpenGLRenderer errors in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I am having big problems when trying to create own Android drawables based on custom bade png files. The issue is similar to a previous one that I posted some days before (and that has not been resolved: [Rendering error in Android's image view by using custom made png file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76943778/rendering-error-in-androids-image-view-by-using-custom-made-png-file)).

I have the following custom made drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            <solid android:color="#c07313" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/coal_icon"
        android:width="29dp"
        android:height="29dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:top
            ="1dp"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical" />
</layer-list>
```

with the custom made png file "coal_icon"

[image]

that I made with Inscape as a vector graphic file and I saved it into the drawable folder of my Android app. However, when an ImageView which should use the custom made drawable as the background should be displayed in my app, I get an unspecific OpernGLRender error and the app crashes (here is just a part of it as the message is quite long):

```
023-08-25 11:31:57.801 12546-12571 OpenGLRenderer          com.example.game                     E  GL error:  GL_INVALID_OPERATION
2023-08-25 11:31:57.801 12546-12571 OpenGLRenderer          com.example.game                     A  GL errors! frameworks/base/libs/hwui/pipeline/skia/SkiaOpenGLPipeline.cpp:127
2023-08-25 11:31:57.855 12546-12571 om.example.gam          com.example.game                     A  runtime.cc:655] Runtime aborting...
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655] Dumping all threads without mutator lock held
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655] All threads:
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655] DALVIK THREADS (14):
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655] "RenderThread" prio=10 tid=18 Runnable
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x13340718 self=0xe4a91810
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | sysTid=12571 nice=-10 cgrp=top-app sched=0/0 handle=0xc33251e0
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | state=R schedstat=( 8290970061 745199188 7990 ) utm=33 stm=795 core=1 HZ=100
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | stack=0xc322a000-0xc322c000 stackSize=1008KB
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #00 pc 00542d9e  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*, bool)+110)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #01 pc 006a0897  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+1015)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #02 pc 0069a171  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+65)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #03 pc 006c61b4  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::DumpCheckpoint::Run(art::Thread*)+1172)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #04 pc 006bf266  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::ThreadList::RunCheckpoint(art::Closure*, art::Closure*)+630)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #05 pc 006be1ce  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::ThreadList::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool)+2446)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #06 pc 0065227d  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::AbortState::DumpAllThreads(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, art::Thread*) const+445)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #07 pc 0063984f  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+1967)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #08 pc 00025a23  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libartbase.so (std::__1::__function::__func<void (*)(char const*), std::__1::allocator<void (*)(char const*)>, void (char const*)>::operator()(char const*&&)+35)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #09 pc 0001588f  /system/lib/libbase.so (android::base::SetAborter(std::__1::function<void (char const*)>&&)::$_3::__invoke(char const*)+79)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #10 pc 00006dbd  /system/lib/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+285)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #11 pc 0024dd11  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::SkiaOpenGLPipeline::swapBuffers(android::uirenderer::renderthread::Frame const&, bool, SkRect const&, android::uirenderer::FrameInfo*, bool*)+145)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #12 pc 00257e78  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::CanvasContext::draw()+1112)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #13 pc 0025ab5f  /system/lib/libhwui.so (_ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread13DrawFrameTask11postAndWaitEvE3$_0NS_9allocatorIS6_EEFvvEEclEv$c303f2d2360db58ed70a2d0ac7ed911b+767)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #14 pc 0024542d  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::WorkQueue::process()+285)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #15 pc 0026cabf  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+127)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #16 pc 00015116  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+374)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #17 pc 000147d9  /system/lib/libutils.so (thread_data_t::trampoline(thread_data_t const*)+457)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #18 pc 000e6974  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+100)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #19 pc 00078567  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+71)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   (no managed stack frames)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655] 
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655] "main" prio=10 tid=1 Native
2023-08-25 11:31:57.855 12546-12571 om.example.gam          com.example.game                     A  runtime.cc:655]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x71401c28 self=0xe4a80e10
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | sysTid=12546 nice=-10 cgrp=top-app sched=0/0 handle=0xf2ed1478
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | state=S schedstat=( 2688356931 656401896 5291 ) utm=144 stm=124 core=0 HZ=100
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | stack=0xff484000-0xff486000 stackSize=8192KB
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | held mutexes=
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #00 pc 00000b97  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+7)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #01 pc 0005ad68  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (syscall+40)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #02 pc 0007725e  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__futex_wait_ex(void volatile*, bool, int, bool, timespec const*)+142)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #03 pc 000e5b2e  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (pthread_cond_wait+62)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #04 pc 0025a146  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::DrawFrameTask::postAndWait()+182)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #05 pc 0023922d  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::android_view_ThreadedRenderer_syncAndDrawFrame(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, long long, _jlongArray*, int)+109)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at android.graphics.HardwareRenderer.nSyncAndDrawFrame(Native method)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at android.graphics.HardwareRenderer.syncAndDrawFrame(HardwareRenderer.java:433)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:658)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:4101)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:3828)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3099)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native method)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655] 
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655] "Signal Catcher" prio=10 tid=6 WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x13340268 self=0xe4a80010
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | sysTid=12556 nice=-20 cgrp=top-app sched=0/0 handle=0xd9cd21e0
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | state=S schedstat=( 688585 0 1 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | stack=0xd9bd7000-0xd9bd9000 stackSize=1008KB
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | held mutexes=
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #00 pc 00000b99  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+9)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #01 pc 000ce821  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__rt_sigtimedwait+33)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #02 pc 00086c55  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (sigwait+69)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #03 pc 00665f1d  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::SignalCatcher::WaitForSignal(art::Thread*, art::SignalSet&)+461)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #04 pc 006648ff  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::SignalCatcher::Run(void*)+479)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #05 pc 000e6974  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+100)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #06 pc 00078567  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+71)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   (no managed stack frames)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655] 
2023-08-25 11:31:57.855 12546-12571 om.example.gam          com.example.game                     A  runtime.cc:655] "perfetto_hprof_listener" prio=10 tid=7 Native (still starting up)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x0 self=0xe4a83810
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | sysTid=12557 nice=-20 cgrp=top-app sched=0/0 handle=0xd9bd11e0
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | state=S schedstat=( 686318 100287 8 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1 HZ=100
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | stack=0xd9ad6000-0xd9ad8000 stackSize=1008KB
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | held mutexes=
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #00 pc 00000b97  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+7)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #01 pc 000ccf9c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (read+28)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #02 pc 0001aca2  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libperfetto_hprof.so (void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, ArtPlugin_Initialize::$_29> >(void*)+306)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #03 pc 000e6974  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+100)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #04 pc 00078567  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+71)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   (no managed stack frames)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655] 
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655] "ADB-JDWP Connection Control Thread" prio=10 tid=8 WaitingInMainDebuggerLoop
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x133402e0 self=0xe4a87e10
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | sysTid=12558 nice=-20 cgrp=top-app sched=0/0 handle=0xd9ad01e0
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | state=S schedstat=( 1594143 693720 6 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3 HZ=100
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | stack=0xd99d5000-0xd99d7000 stackSize=1008KB
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | held mutexes=
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #00 pc 00000b99  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+9)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #01 pc 000cf496  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__ppoll+38)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #02 pc 00083979  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (poll+105)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #03 pc 0000a493  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libadbconnection.so (adbconnection::AdbConnectionState::RunPollLoop(art::Thread*)+1171)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #04 pc 000086d2  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libadbconnection.so (adbconnection::CallbackFunction(void*)+1666)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #05 pc 000e6974  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+100)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #06 pc 00078567  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+71)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   (no managed stack frames)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655] 
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655] "Jit thread pool worker thread 0" prio=5 tid=9 Native
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x13340358 self=0xe4a8d210
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | sysTid=12559 nice=0 cgrp=top-app sched=0/0 handle=0xc4d74d60
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | state=S schedstat=( 933177212 340822158 1157 ) utm=32 stm=60 core=0 HZ=100
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | stack=0xc4c76000-0xc4c78000 stackSize=1023KB
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   | held mutexes=
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #00 pc 00000b97  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+7)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #01 pc 0005ad68  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (syscall+40)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #02 pc 001d82ec  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*)+108)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #03 pc 001d8273  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::Wait(art::Thread*)+35)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #04 pc 006c838f  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::ThreadPool::GetTask(art::Thread*)+143)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #05 pc 006c73e5  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::ThreadPoolWorker::Run()+133)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #06 pc 006c6e9d  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::ThreadPoolWorker::Callback(void*)+269)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #07 pc 000e6974  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+100)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   native: #08 pc 00078567  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+71)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]   (no managed stack frames)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:655]
```

The Java code for the backend itself is correct as I don't get this error at all (tested it 1000 times) when using just an Android Studio internal vector asset in the custom made drawable for `android:drawable="@drawable/vector_asset_from_android_studio"`

Can someone explain why I get this error when using custom made drawables with custom made png files?

**Reminder**: Does anyone have an idea why this error occurs and what ot do to solve this issue? As I want to use my own custom made icons in my apps, I don't want to look for other icons in the internet.

Comment: sir, your xml code also worked successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to export your file as `SVG` file as follow:

- Select the object(s) to export
- Open the document properties window (Ctrl+Shift+D)
- Select "Resize page to drawing or selection"
- File > Save As Copy...
- Select Optimized SVG as the format if you want to use it on the web

the import it into Android studio as follow:
[image]

**Old answer:**

Try `Bitmap` for `png` files:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="5dp" />
                <solid android:color="#c07313" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item
            android:width="29dp"
            android:height="29dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:left="1dp"
            android:bottom="1dp"
            android:top
                ="1dp"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical" >
            <bitmap android:src="@drawable/coal_icon"/> <!-- this -->
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

Comment: Thanks CFG for your answer. I tried it but it does not change anything. I still get the same error.

Comment: @VanessaF: Are you sure that you have implemented this correctly? you have wrote that  _"I made with Inscape as a vector graphic file and I saved it into the drawable folder"_. What is the file format? `png` or `xml` (`svg`)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The code itself should be correct. I tried about 1000 times with drawables provided by Android Studio and I have never seen this error. Whenever I use my own custom made png files I always get this error (I created them using a vector graphic in Inkscape and exportet it as png via Inkscape)

Comment: It has as problem with rendering the png file altough I have no clue why and how to tackle this issue? One workaround is to use the icons provided by Android Studio. But when doing so I am extremely limited in my apps which I don't want to be.

Comment: @VanessaF: Why you don't export it as `svg` then import it into Android Studio?

Comment: `svg` files are same as android studio  icons provided by Android Studio. They are vector files this means that devises can zoom it infinite times, but `png` is not a vector file. it has fix resolution.

Comment: Ah okay, I tried it with svg and it works so far. Thanks for this advice and help. Maybe you can write it as an answer for others (and I would accept it). But still I don't know why the png does not work.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Note if you still want to test using `png` file, try to [add an png for each density](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44514036/6576302).

Comment: Thanks a lot CFG for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

*place this file in drawable side - coal_mine.xml*

```
<vector android:height="80dp" android:viewportHeight="512"
android:viewportWidth="512" android:width="80dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<path android:fillColor="#000000" android:pathData="M365.91,60.84C347.22,62.03 327.73,73.3 307.72,87.5c-20.81,14.77 -41.85,32.27 -64.63,41.88a8,8 0,0 1,-9.13 -2.13c-15.01,-17.31 -38.15,-30.55 -73.22,-27.28 -19.12,1.78 -32.25,10.63 -43.69,23.66 -5.26,6 -10,12.98 -14.53,20.38h322.62c-15.21,-29.85 -29.05,-64.18 -59.25,-83.16zM40,160v44h416v-44L40,160zM58.38,220l49.34,186.56L118,406.56c3.09,-6.59 7.31,-12.68 12.56,-17.94 11.92,-11.92 28.63,-18.91 45.84,-18.91 17.21,0 33.9,6.99 45.81,18.91 5.25,5.25 9.47,11.35 12.56,17.94h42.97c3.1,-6.47 7.28,-12.44 12.41,-17.56 11.93,-11.93 28.38,-18.75 45.25,-18.75 16.87,0 33.32,6.82 45.25,18.75 5.12,5.12 9.3,11.09 12.41,17.56h6.03L438.16,220L58.38,220zM426.22,355l-6.06,29L456,384v-29h-29.78zM176.41,386.56c-11.69,0 -23.73,4.91 -32.25,13.44 -8.52,8.52 -13.75,21 -13.75,33.34 0,12.34 5.23,24.82 13.75,33.34 8.52,8.52 20.56,13.44 32.25,13.44 11.69,0 23.7,-4.91 32.22,-13.44 8.52,-8.52 13.78,-21 13.78,-33.34 0,-12.34 -5.26,-24.82 -13.78,-33.34 -8.52,-8.52 -20.53,-13.44 -32.22,-13.44zM335.41,387.84c-12.04,0 -24.3,5.08 -32.81,13.59C294.08,409.95 289,422.21 289,434.25c0,12.04 5.08,24.3 13.59,32.81 8.51,8.51 20.77,13.59 32.81,13.59 12.04,0 24.3,-5.08 32.81,-13.59 8.51,-8.51 13.59,-20.77 13.59,-32.81 0,-12.04 -5.08,-24.3 -13.59,-32.81 -8.51,-8.51 -20.78,-13.59 -32.81,-13.59z"/></vector>
```

*Go to the browser - and search free SVG icon then download and then open the android studio - select drawable and right click - new - vector asset - open pop up then select SVG radio button and provide your file path and finish. And then used everywhere.*
*Size change any time.*

Comment: Thanks Rahul for your answer. I know that I could seach for svg icons in the internet. But I want to include my own custom made icons in my app (not only for this specific task). This is why it is quite important for me to understand, what is causing the rendering error and how to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

*Step1: *
*Drawable right click -> new -> image assets -> icon type select option (action bar and tab icon) -> asset type (image) -> path (saved image in drawable .png formate), Then Theme -> (custome) -> custome color (as you wish) -> finish.*

[image: image_assets_png]

*Or*
*Step1: *
*Drawable right click -> new -> vector assets -> select any vector then finish*

[image: android_studio_vector]

*Step2: *
*Drawable right click -> new -> drawable resource file name (custom_image) and then OK*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item><shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        <solid android:color="#ffffff" /></shape></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_arrrow"
    android:width="50dp"
    android:height="50dp"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical" /></layer-list>
```

[image: custom_file]

*Step3: *
*Used custom image any imageview*

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/custom_image"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul for your answer. I tried it but it did not change anyhting. I get the very same error message.

Comment: update your build gradle issue